# ERROR [42000] [Microsoft] [ODBC SQL Server Driver] [SQL Server] Incorrect syntax near '.'

Tags: sql-server, odbc

ERROR [42000] [Microsoft] [ODBC SQL Server Driver] [SQL Server] Incorrect syntax near '.'.

Answer (score 0):

Issue is caused by incompatibility issue of SQL Server. Run the query below to set it to at least 90(SQL Server 2005)

```
ALTER DATABASE eportalv2 SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 90;
```